# Dummy Guide for Quick Implementation of HL7 FHIR DSTU2 Ballot Source Version

Tags: hl7-fhir

Are there any dummy guides for quick implementation of HL7 FHIR DSTU2 Ballot Source version?

I had read the HL7 FHIR specifications but I am still confused on how to implement. I am more of a hands-on than theory-based person. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this page: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/overview-dev.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I should read that first before posting more questions here.